# Hibernate Session update not reflecting in database

Tags: java, hibernate, ejb-3.0, weblogic11g

I am using Weblogic 10.3.6 + Hibernate 3 and EJB 3.0

I am trying the update the entity but the its not getting updated in Database.
No exceptions

Please find the hibernate config file as below

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">jdbc/wfAR_ConnectionDS</property>
  <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.hibernate.session_factory_name">wfAR_ConnectionDS</property>
  <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.WeblogicTransactionManagerLookup</property>
  <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory.class">org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory</property>
  <property name="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">false</property>
  <property name="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</property>
  <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
```

and I am using the below code to update the entity in my EJB

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public long updateCustomerData(ArCatCustomer customer){
        long id=-1;
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        try{
            System.out.println("**************Trying to Update***********");
            session.update(customer);
            //session.evict(customer);
            session.flush();
            System.out.println("***********Update Finished***********");
        }catch(RuntimeException runExp){
            runExp.printStackTrace();
            throw runExp;
        } finally{
            session.close();
        }
        return id;
    }
```

I could see the below in the console:

```
**************Trying to Update***********
Hibernate: 
    /* update
        com.ar.flextronics.model.ArCatCustomer */ update
            AR_catCustomer 
        set
            SegmentID=?,
            MepID=?,
            ParentCustomerID=?,
            CustomerNumber=?,
            CustomerName=?,
            VendorID=?,
            LocalVATID=?,
            [FlexCustomer-Supplier]=?,
            VMI=?,
            TypeOfBilling=?,
            CreditTerms=?,
            CustomerCurrencyID=?,
            CreditRate=?,
            CreditLimit=?,
            ParentBPNumInsideCompany=?,
            LegalEntityname=?,
            Region=?,
            Active=?,
            ERPName=?,
            ERPServer=?,
            ERPFinanceCompanyNumber=?,
            ERPLogisticCompanyNumber=?,
            LastUpdate=?,
            UpdatedBy=?,
            CustomerTypeID=? 
        where
            CustomerID=?
***********Update Finished***********
```

But the data is not getting saved in database.

Please help me to resolve. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I dont see in your hibernate configuration property:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</property>
```

Since default configuration = false. Set this and check the results.

But if you want to do this manually you need to:

```
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
//your code
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Comment: Thanks its started working. I used autocommit property.